# Java: Reading a file, first line missing

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have an `HashMap<String, String>` which keeps the filename and the display name of an image. I read a file line by line and add the key and values to HashMap.

```
BufferedReader reader;
String line;
String[] lineSplit;

HashMap<String, String> imenaZnaki = new HashMap<String, String>();

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open("znaki_imena.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        lineSplit = line.split("->");
        imenaZnaki.put(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1]);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything works as expected, except for the first added entry, the `.get(key)` returns null and `.containsKey(key)` returns false. All the other key/values work and are properly stored in the HashMap.

**EDIT:**

This makes no sense at all... After I added the content to HashMap I runned the code that MagicMan provided to check if all the entrys are inside the HashMap

```
for(String key: imenaZnaki.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("KEY: " + key + "  VALUE: " + imenaZnaki.get(key));
}
```

And if I would <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> for "nevar_andrej" it would show me 4 outputs, which is correct. But if I searched for " nevar_andrej" (with a whitespace) it would only show 3 of them, which is wrong, because the first one would be missing. So my guess is, that there is something in the first line of the file that causes confusion. So I added a dummy/fake first line (bla_bla->Bla bla) and it works, but it is a nasty workaround.

This is my full text file that is encoded with UTF-8 http://pastebin.com/6A4r4jm6

Comment: Step through it in the debugger. It is **extremely** unlikely that `get` and `containsKey` have bugs for storing `String`s.

Comment: What is the first line in the file?  It probably doesn't have a "->" in the correct location

Comment: did you debug it? and see if what give you `line.split("->") in first iteration?

Comment: show us the file you are reading

Comment: I have edited my question and added the first couple of lines of the file. After spliting first line I have added the System.out.println and printed the lineSplit[0] and lineSplit[1] and it gives me the correct key/value. I haven't done any proper debugging with debugger yet.

Comment: Shouldn't you reset lineSplit.? I mean if it's iterating over it, the array is growing and you are using the same index.I'm nt sure if thats the problem but you can probably try it out. Or use a counter for it.

Comment: Use HashMap.keySet() to dump the set of keys that are in the map. Are you sure your key isn't in it? There's a good chance this is some sort of encoding bug - I'm guessing that the version of the "nevar_andrejev..." string your testing with is somehow slightly different than whats actually in the file. You can try looking at your source and the text file in a hex reader to compare the strings and ensure they're the same byte-for-byte.

Comment: I ran this really quick locally and it seems to work correctly for me with the sample you gave. It worked correctly for all 7 pairs calling get while iterating over the keyset. How many lines is the file total?

Comment: @user2339071 - arrays in java don't grow. You can create a new array that's bigger, but they don't grow. At that, you'll notice that lineSplit comes from the String.split() function, which allocates a new array every time it is invoked.

Comment: I did not know that. :D .. Learnt something new today.. :P

Comment: I have edited my question with further "investigation", something seems to be wrong with the first line of the file.

Comment: Wondering if there could be a BOM issue on that first line: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark Try re-saving/re-encoding the file and see what happens.

Comment: I have created a new text file and copied the content, saved it as UTF-8 encoding and the problem was still there. Than I tried with a different encoding, that is Unicode, also I had changed the InputStreamReader encoding to "unicode" and it seems to work. Looks like somekind of encoding bug as @antiduh had suggested? Any idea why UTF-8 would have a problem with first line? Make/edit an answer to the question and i'll accept it. Thanks for help!

Comment: "Unicode" here means UTF-16 ("Unicode" is not an encoding - its a system that assigns values to glyphs and glyph modifiers; it makes no mention as to how to store those values on disk or in memory); Microsoft can be stupid sometimes.. C# internally stores values as UTF-16, so there's a chance that something is going wrong when you're copying the content around to put into your text file and your code, and it just so happens that it works correctly when you use UTF-16. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are fully capable of representing the entire unicode code space.

Comment: Updated my answer again; fiddled around with the text file encoding, think that's the root of the issue. Some good info in antiduh's comments too.

Comment: After realizing my knowledge on encodings was really poor I stumbled upon a great article with a title: 

The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the code below and see if all of your entries are present:

```
for(String key: imenaZnaki.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("KEY: " + key + "  VALUE: " + imenaZnaki.get(key));
}
```

I was able to run your code and your sample and get all 7 entries to pop up in there. See antiduh's comment if doesn't work correctly for you; you're probably running into an encoding issue with your string you're using in the get() call.

This is run from OS X,

Console output specifying UTF-8 as the format:

```
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna  VALUE: Andrejev kri? (?elezni?ka proga je dvo ali ve?tirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna_2  VALUE: Andrejev kri? (?elezni?ka proga je dvo ali ve?tirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna  VALUE: Andrejev kri? (?elezni?ka proga je enotirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna_2  VALUE: Andrejev kri? (?elezni?ka proga je enotirna)
KEY: nevar_blizina_letaliske_steze  VALUE: Bli?ina letali?ke steze
KEY: nevar_blizina_obale  VALUE: Bli?ina obale
KEY: nevar_blizina_svetlobnih_prometnih_znakov  VALUE: Bli?ina svetlobnih prometnih znakov
```

**UPDATE**

So this appears to be an issue the BOM(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being read. I originally re-saved the file as UTF-8, and it produced the output above. I then resaved the file with encoding "UTF-8 with BOM" and it produced this:

```
KEY: ???nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna  VALUE: Andrejev kri?? (??elezni??ka proga je dvo ali ve??tirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna_2  VALUE: Andrejev kri?? (??elezni??ka proga je dvo ali ve??tirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna  VALUE: Andrejev kri?? (??elezni??ka proga je enotirna)
KEY: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna_2  VALUE: Andrejev kri?? (??elezni??ka proga je enotirna)
KEY: nevar_blizina_letaliske_steze  VALUE: Bli??ina letali??ke steze
KEY: nevar_blizina_obale  VALUE: Bli??ina obale
KEY: nevar_blizina_svetlobnih_prometnih_znakov  VALUE: Bli??ina svetlobnih prometnih znakov
```

Notice the three ? characters at the front of the first line. Those are the BOM characters look like this in hex: EF BB BF. That is likely what was causing your issues with the first line. Try resaving the file without a BOM using a text editor like Notepad++ or SublimeText

Comment: Ill second this, someplace an encoding issue must be creating inequality.

Comment: Read my edited question on further "investigation" ;)

Comment: Originally I was using the plain Notepad, after downloading Notepad++ I did what you said and it works like a charm. Was not aware this could be an issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Im calling Shennanegans...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    String[] lineSplit;

    HashMap<String, String> imenaZnaki = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
        String firstKey, firstValue;
        firstKey = null;
        firstValue = null;
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            lineSplit = line.split("->");
            if (firstKey == null) {
                firstKey = lineSplit[0];
                firstValue = lineSplit[1];
            }
            imenaZnaki.put(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        System.out.println("contains first split line key: " +  imenaZnaki.containsKey(firstKey));
        System.out.println("contains first split key text dupe: " + imenaZnaki.containsKey("nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna"));
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : imenaZnaki.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " " + "value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Console output:

```
contains first split line key: true
contains first split key text dupe: true
key: nevar_blizina_letaliske_steze value: BliÅ¾ina letaliÅ¡ke steze
key: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna_2 value: Andrejev kriÅ¾ (Å¾elezniÅ¡ka proga je dvo ali veÄ?tirna)
key: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna value: Andrejev kriÅ¾ (Å¾elezniÅ¡ka proga je enotirna)
key: nevar_blizina_obale value: BliÅ¾ina obale
key: nevar_blizina_svetlobnih_prometnih_znakov value: BliÅ¾ina svetlobnih prometnih znakov
key: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_dvo_ali_vectirna value: Andrejev kriÅ¾ (Å¾elezniÅ¡ka proga je dvo ali veÄ?tirna)
key: nevar_andrejev_kriz_zelezniska_proga_je_enotirna_2 value: Andrejev kriÅ¾ (Å¾elezniÅ¡ka proga je enotirna)
```

Comment: Your output is garbled - you've got an encoding problem too :)

Comment: I didnt specify encoding, so I expect its converting UTF-8 which the file test.txt is saved in, into win-1252 both in the source code with the literal, and as the bytes in the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not in the hashmap
it it within the file format,I change the file format to GBK as well as the related reading code, I can access the key